# How can I convert a temporary String to a &str?

Tags: rust, format, lifetime

I wish to convert a `String` created using the `format!` macro to a `&str` and assign this to a value using a `let` binding:

```
fn main() {
    let my_bool = true;
    let other = String::from("my_string");
    let result = if my_bool {
        format!("_{}", other).as_str()
    } else {
        "other"
    };

    println!("{}", result);
}
```

([Rust Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a02f15ecac0a1aff2c1998988b9a7e4e))

When I do this, the compiler complains that the temporary `String` value is freed at the end of the statement (from what I've understood), meaning that I'm unable to dynamically create a `&str`:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:5:9
  |
4 |     let result = if my_bool {
  |         ------ borrow later stored here
5 |         format!("_{}", other).as_str()
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
6 |     } else {
  |     - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |
```

I've been trying to understand Rust's lifetime system, but I can't really wrap my head around this one. Rust suggests the following:

```
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

I wrapped `format!("_{}", other)` in a `let` binding:

```
fn main() {
    let my_bool = true;
    let other = String::from("my_string");
    let result = if my_bool {
        let s = format!("_{}", other);
        s.as_str()
    } else {
        "other"
    };

    println!("{}", result);
}
```

But it doesn't seem to solve the issue, as when I call `as_str()` on this binding it still complains that the borrowed value does not live long enough:

```
error[E0597]: `s` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
4 |     let result = if my_bool {
  |         ------ borrow later stored here
5 |         let s = format!("_{}", other);
6 |         s.as_str()
  |         ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
7 |     } else {
  |     - `s` dropped here while still borrowed
```

This works when I omit the whole `if`, but I would rather not do this as this would cause a lot of headaches in the original code base.

Also, that does seem like kind of a cop-out, because then I still wouldn't know why this fails.

How would I go about solving this in a systematic manner?

Comment: Why do you want a `str` in the first place? If you convert it to a `str` what would be responsible for owning that memory? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c7d3b896cb0865e70f0ce501492de439 works great.

Comment: @loganfsmyth the reason for wanting a `str` is that this is part of a match statement which returns `str`s, and I would rather that in this case I could return a `str` instead of having to wrap every match case in a `String::from(...)`

Comment: A `&str` is a borrowed value, so in order to return one, the memory being borrowed needs to live somewhere. If your `match` is required to return a `&str` then you are explicitly limiting yourself to returning borrowed values that already existed somewhere before the match ran, which means you can't create a new `String` in there.

Comment: @loganfsmyth oh that makes more sense.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your question](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e28770b663ae828f1bbdd5814f676d6a) (this was originally a standalone answer).

Answer (score 10):

`&str` is a **borrowed** string, so you cannot get one from a temporary `String`, otherwise a reference would outlive the value it is bound to.

There are 2 solutions to palliate this problem:

---

You can create a new variable to store the `String` out of the `if` scope:

```rust
fn main() {
    let my_bool = true;
    let other = String::from("my_string");
    
    let result;
    let result = if my_bool {
        result = format!("_{}", other);
        result.as_str()
    } else {
        "other"
    };

    println!("{}", result);
}
```

---

You can use the [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) type to do what you want:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn main() {
    let my_bool = true;
    let other = String::from("my_string");
    let result = if my_bool {
        Cow::Owned(format!("_{}", other))
    } else {
        Cow::Borrowed("other")
    };

    assert_eq!("_my_string", result);
}
```

`Cow` (for *clone on write*) is an `enum` that have either an owned or a borrowed data. In this particular case, `result` has the type `Cow<str>`.

You can simplify the notation by writing:

```
let result = if my_bool {
    format!("_{}", other).into()
} else {
    Cow::Borrowed("other")
};
```

or (matter of style):

```
let result: Cow<str> = if my_bool {
    format!("_{}", other).into()
} else {
    "other".into()
};
```

Comment: I encourage moving / adding this answer to the duplicate.

Comment: whats wrong with `.as_str()` ?

Comment: @alexzander There is nothing wrong with it. What is wrong is to leak a reference to a variable outside of this variable scope: the variable `s` which is created in the `if` scope is destroyed at the end of that scope. So if the OP's code had compiled, the `result` variable would have pointed to the freed memory, which is unsafe.

Comment: Your first solution is wrong. You are mutating an inmutable value. `result` needs to be `mut` and now it will work.

Comment: @SantiagoAlejandroTorresArag I just copy/pasted my code and try and compile it, it works perfectly fine as is. Maybe what confuses you is the variable shadowing I use. See this version without shadowing, maybe it's clearer: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d5f20e25108bd3c60c684574ed2341cc